Ping an user in the question
We all know that to notify a user that we're mentioning them, we use @<user> in comments. I was wondering if the same happens when we write @<user> in a question.

No, you can't ping a user in a question

No, you can't ping a user as part of a post (question or answer). Pinging is only possible in chat and post comments. For the latter it is only for select users who had an interaction with the post (post authors, other commentors with visible comments, post editors, certain post closers).
FAQ reference: How do comment @replies work?

Thank you very much.
